# How can I add a linked source folder in Android Studio?

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio

In Eclipse I can add a source folder to my Android project as a "linked source folder". How do I achieve the same thing in Android Studio?

Or is it possible to add an external folder to build in Gradle?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In your *build.gradle* file, add the following to the end of the Android node:

```
android {
    ....
    ....

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
    }

}
```

Comment: Really helpful. Why put `sourceSets` in the scope of `android`? My `dependencies` is out of it.

Comment: But this solution deals only with the Java files. What about all the resources that under 'src' as well - the drawable, layouts, strings, etc. How to be able to put them in an external folder?

Comment: For appengine, sourceSets must be at root level - not nested within.  Rather strange that it would be one  way for android modules and another way for appengine modules.

Comment: I take it there's no support for the include/exclude options that Eclipse has.  Too bad.

Comment: I don't have android block in my build.gradle. Should I add?

Comment: @Deckard There should be an android block in the build.gradle of the module "app", not in the root build file.

Comment: Note that also absolute paths can be used - the directories then appear next to the existing "src" directory in Android Studio, not inside. When symlinking them inside *and* adding them as source dirs, one gets "duplicate class" errors. See also my comment to the symlink answer.

Comment: @GyRo You can do the same for resources files: in sourceSets add the line `main.res.srcDirs += '<YOUR DIRECTORY>'`

Comment: I have no idea what an "Anrdriod node" is. Thereore your score now is -1.

Comment: What about native sources? `main.WhatGoesHere.srcDirs += 'src/'`

Answer (score 24):

The right answer is:

```
android {
    ....
    ....

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if your external source directory is not under `src/main`, you could use a relative path like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/../../../<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
}
```

Comment: Regarding relative paths - I wonder if it is possible to use some sort of gradle variables, eg.  srcDirs += "$(ProjectDir)/mylib/src"?   I'm new to Gradle and have no idea if it supports anything like this.

Comment: You can omit the `src/main/../../` prefix since the dots cancel the path components.

Comment: @BrianWhite how do I specify a source set on another machine? `sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/\\10.51.70.21\me\myco\apps\myapp\src'
}`

Comment: I don't expect you can since, as far as I know, it just uses the OS `open()` to access files.  You could use something like `nfs` or `smb` to mount remote directories right into the file system but that's not specific to Android Studio.

Comment: While this solution works, I found that it will not work if you have a project made up from several modules and more than one module wants to reference the same external source code. It appears that only one module can reference external source files. This is a shame, as I had intended on having a common src folder that I could use to share constants without the need to create a jar or aar file.

Comment: The relative path usage worked well for me with an external C++ native library, just had to make sure I set the `cmake { } ` path in Gradle to relative also. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a source folder to the build script and then sync.  Look for sourceSets in the documentation here:  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Project

I haven't found a good way of adding test source folders.  I have manually added the source to the .iml file.  Of course this means it will go away everytime the build script is synched.

Answer (score 2):

While `sourceSets` allows you to include entire directory structures, there's no way to exclude parts of it in Android Studio (as of version 1.2), as described in *[Exclude a class from the build in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build)*.

Until Android Studio gets updated to support include/exclude directives for Android sources, [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) work quite well.  If you're using Windows, native tools such as `junction` or `mklink` can accomplish the equivalent of symbolic links on Unix-like systems.  [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) can also create these with a little coercion.  See: *[Git symbolic links in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows/30457566#30457566)* and *[How to make a symbolic link with Cygwin in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7)*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following behaviour in Android Studio 2.1.2 with symlinks: the files are shown next to the project files and with a clean build it works. But every normal build after changes in the symlinked directories gives a gradle error: "Unable to find source java class: '<full-absolute-path>/<added directory>/MyClass.java' because it does not belong to any of the source dirs: [list of src dirs including ".../src/main/java" where in a package folder the symlink resides]".

Comment: @user905686 Yes! Holy cow. It's taken me hours to find somebody else running into this same problem. Like you said, symlinks work on a clean "rebuild" but not on subsequent runs. It's far too time consuming so I've just updated my settings to reference the actual directory instead of symlinking. Kind of a pain but it makes development way faster.

Comment: I have added bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65343978, but I'm not sure if it will be accepted as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a complete Java module Gradle file that correctly generates and references the built artefacts within an Android multi-module application:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.15"
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "idea"

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main")
        testSourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/test")
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Dagger 2 and Compiler
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15"
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre"

}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
android {
    sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs("src/main/myDirectory/code/")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/main/myDirectory/resources/")

    // Another notation:
    // sourceSets {
    //     getByName("main") {
    //         java.srcDirs("src/main/myDirectory/code/")
    //         resources.srcDirs("src/main/myDirectory/resources/")
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen I updated the link. Thanks for pointing that out. Mmm... and forgive me if I have not used the proper article.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Gradle (creating a project from an [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29), for instance), this can be done through the Android Studio UI (as of version 3.3.2):

- Right-click the project root directory and pick *Open Module Settings*
- Hit the <kbd>+ Add Content Root</kbd> button (center right)
- Add your path and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

In my experience (with native code), as long as your `.so` files are built with debug symbols and from the same absolute paths, breakpoints added in source files will be automatically recognized.

Comment: Lost me at point 2... Can't see no Add Content Root button.