# How to add a linked source folder from a remote machine in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to follow this [post How to add a linked source folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947314/how-to-add-a-linked-source-folder-in-android-studio),

I tried

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/\\\\10.11.12.13\\me\\workspace\\myapp\\src'
}
```

However it does not display the source folder.
If I do

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '\\\\10.11.12.13\\me\\workspace\\myapp\\src'
}
```

Then the sources are visible but outside my project app tree. How to get them inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

in app/main/build.gradle

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '\\\\\\10.11.12.13\\me\\workspace\\myapp\\src'
    }
}
```