# How to add and use an external Java source folder in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I need to use this [java source code](https://github.com/DSpace/xoai) to retrieve data from a public educational repository. How can I add this folder to my Android Studio project, and the project recognize it?

Every search I make in Google results in how to add .jar or .aar libraries. This is just a source folder with java classes.

Use of Android Studio is a must for this assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: copy and paste the folder into `src/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a linked source folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947314/how-to-add-a-linked-source-folder-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it via Gradle in the project with

`dependencies {
   compile project(':Dependency')
}`.

Also add it to settings.gradle like this

`include ':Dependency'
project(':Dependency').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Dependency')`

Read more [here](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/).

Comment: Thanks.
i tried this, and other similar answers, but the project seems to be unable to resolve the dependency. I created a directory at the root of the project called libraries, copied and pasted xaoi-master in that directory, added the [code](include ':libraries:xaoi-master') in settings.gradle, and the [code]dependencies { compile project('libraries:xoai-master')} in build.gradle, with no successful sync