# Trying to android ndk and cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, cocos2d-x

i am trying to build andriod - cocos2d-x-2.2.5 project which just a simple hello world project but when i try to run by entering ./build-native.sh in cygwin i got following warning and i am not able to proceed further.

```
$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = C:\android-ndk-r10d
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/helloWorld/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/helloWorld/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/helloWorld/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/helloWorld/proj.android'
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-all.mk:89: Android NDK: ***WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!***
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/cocos2d-x-2.2.5/projects/helloWorld/proj.android'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

`WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!`

can happen if you haven't created the symbolic link in the release NDK directory.

You can read more about the issue [here](https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2013/10/04/mucking-around-with-libc-on-android/).

How to create symbolic links when using cygwin is addressed in this SO post:

[How to make symbolic link with cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7)