# GVM Error Setting Default Groovy Version

Tags: groovy, gvm, sdkman

I installed groovy with GVM:

```
gvm install groovy
```

But when I say yes to the set 2.4.6 as default version, I get this error:

```
rm: `/c/Users/<user_name>/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current' is a directory
ln: `/c/Users/<user_name>/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current': cannot overwrite direc
tory
```

Not sure why it's trying to rm the current folder but then create a symbolic link to it. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Windows

Comment: I thought so. GVM/SDK Man is for *NIX operating systems. It is not for Windows. You can use Posh-GVM instead. Or, if you're feeling adventurous and want to keep using cygwin see this regading symbolic links on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648819/how-to-make-symbolic-link-with-cygwin-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

`current` should be a symbolic link to the directory of your current version, not a directory itself

Looks like for some reason, it's currently a directory

Try moving `current` out of the way, and trying again

PS: gvm is now called sdkman and the command is `sdk` not `gvm` though `gvm` still currently works for historic compatibility

Answer (score 0):

From the name it looks like you are on "[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys)" shell.   `sdkman`  cannot handle the softlinks in this environment.

Delete `current` directory and copy the version you want to use. This is not a groovy issue; affects all tools available under sdkman (such as lazybone, grails..)